# Jenkins on Windows using something other than ant

Tags: ant, window, jenkins

I am looking at using Jenkins on Windows.
I currently have an ant script. It works pretty well. Except for instance, when the build breaks because of a syntax error, I can not see the error in the Jenkins console log.

So I am thinking may be ant is not the best tool for use on Windows.
What do most of you use for Jenkins on Windows?

If it is ant, how do you send the build output, VStudio, to the Jenkins console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dev.cmd shows the output and I continue to use ant.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily I use Jenkins with [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) projects, although you should see the ANT output in the online logs regardless.

Answer (score 0):

What are you building? Are you building Java projects? Ant is what you use. If you are bulding a C project, you should use Make. If you're building a VisualStudio project, you should use msbuild. You use the build tool for your project. Jenkins will execute them without a problem.

Take a look at the build in question. On the left side of the screen, there's a Console output item. Click on that. Is there any output. No matter what tool you use, Jenkins captures the STDOUT and STDERR in that console output. If nothing else, you should see the exact commands Jenkins is executing to checkout and to build your project. Try executing those commands.

Still, you didn't give us much to go on. No idea what you're building or what you're doing with Ant. You didn't state any error, the console output, or even what the Jenkins error log is stating.

Jenkins does two things:

- It watches your repository for changes.
- Once it detects the changes, it executes the very commands you'd execute to build the project.

Jenkins doesn't care whether you use Ant, Maven, Make, or simply do a `del /s/q`. Jenkins will simply execute the commands you tell it to execute.

---

#### Addendum

> It is c, c++, Java and InstallShield. I use ant to do file copy and move, call msdev.exe project. Some Javac calls, InstallShield command line builds..

Jenkins can execute multiple step builds in a single job. After you specify the build step, you can press the **Add** button to add another build step. There's no reason that all the build steps even have to be of the same type. Just select a "Freestyle" build, and use the right build tools for the job.

There's an optional [MSBUILD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) in Jenkins that should do your MS Build. This should give you the complete output from MSBuild, so you can see any errors.

After you do your MSBuild step, you can create a **second** build step to run an Ant task to build your InstallShield. After that, you could run another build step to do the copying you need either on the command line or through something like Ant (or [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/).

Whatever the output of the various tools is the output you'll get in the build console.

Comment: it is c, c++, Java and InstallShield. I use ant to do file copy and move, call msdev.exe project. Some Javac calls, InstallShield command line builds...

Comment: For instance, when I get a compile error, it says that the line in the xml file that has runs the command failed. So for instance msdev project failed, as opposed file.cpp compile error at line 42.